# Como puedo cambiar el contenido de un <p> desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

y queria saber como cambiar el contenido de un parrafo desde javascript. Ejemplo:

```
<p id="parrafo"></p>
```

creo que se usa un getElementById, pero no se como usarlo exactamente. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Exacto. Alcanzas el elemento por su id y cambias su contenido. Si ese contenido no tiene etiquetas HTML, lo más seguro es usar `textContent`. Investiga, intenta algo y si no lo logras, te ayudaremos a hacerlo funcionar. Tu pregunta no muestra ningún esfuerzo por resolver un problema bastante sencillo.

Comment: Intente buscarlo pero no encontre una que me respondiera directamente, perdona

Comment: Ya, pero si buscas `getElementById()`  en internet verás la documentación, la leerás, empezarás a entender cómo funciona. Luego ensayarás un código y justo cuando estés bloqueado, preguntarás aquí y te ayudaremos. Si te lo damos hecho no vas a aprender y no vas a investigar y a la larga será peor para ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar varias propiedades para modificar el **contenido** de un elemento html. Si quieres solamente añadir *contenido como texto* te recomiendo modificar `element.textContent`:

```js
let parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');



setTimeout(() => {
    parrafo.textContent += ' y un segundo después hay más contenido';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id='parrafo'>Esto es un texto simple</p>
```

Comment: @LaureanoSciacaluga para ejecutar código luego de un tiempo establecido... 1000 milisegundos equivalen a 1 segundo. aquí puedes encontrar más información https://es.javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 5):

Puedes ocupar el metodo `innerText` o `innerHTML`.

El metodo `innerText` es para agregar contenido de formato `String` y el metodo `innerHTML` es para agregar String en estructura **HTML**.

```js
const p = document.getElementById("parrafo")
const p2 = document.getElementById("parrafo2")


p.innerText = "Esto es un texto simple"
p2.innerHTML = "<h2>Esto es inserción de <code>html</code></h2>"
```

```html
<p id="parrafo"></p>

<p id="parrafo2"></p>
```

Saludos.

Comment: **Aviso de seguridad:** Usar `innerHTML` no es seguro ([viene advertido en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#consideraci%C3%B3n_de_seguridad)). Una pequeña prueba. Crea esto: `const fake = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>;"` y luego pon esto así: `"<h2>Esto es inserción de <code>html</code></h2>"+fake;` y prueba el código. Verás que el `alert` se inyecta en el código. Pero, como te inyectan un simple `alert` pueden inyectarte cosas peores. Conviene usar `createElement` para no comprometer la seguridad.

Comment: @A.Cedano interesante tu comentario, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
const párrafo  = docuement.querySelector('#párrafo');
```

con esa linea ya accedes al párrafo con el `id="párrafo"`. Ahora de que tipo de **contenido quieres modificar, si es texto**

```
parrafo.textContent = 'Nuevo texto';
```

Si buscas otra clase de modificadores te invito que visites el [siguiente enlace](http://mialtoweb.es/modificar-html-con-javascript/)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español! Es genial que quieras aportar, pero la comunidad tiene una serie de normas para preguntar y responder de forma adecuada. La idea es generar contenido de calidad para el OP y para futuros visitantes que tengan un problema similar. Te sugiero hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas lo que te comento y también te sugiero editar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo accediendo al elemento con document.getElementById y luego a este elemento le cambias su texto con innerHTML de la siguiente forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center bg-warning p-4">
                <p id="parrafo"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Requerir BootStrap -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"                 integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"                       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- requerir Sweet Alert -->
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        //Capturo el objeto del DOM
        var p = document.getElementById('parrafo');

        //Cambio el texto del elemento
        p.innerHTML = 'Aqui cambio mi texto'

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```